# Grouping and sorting based condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

l have the following table and data and expected output with my rules

```
drop table test_new

create table test_new (id number(9), loc1 number(9), loc2 number(9), percentage number(9));

insert into test_new values (1,1,2,0);
insert into test_new values(2,1,3,10);
insert into test_new values(3,1,4,5);
insert into test_new values(4,1,5,45);
insert into test_new values(5,2,3,0);
insert into test_new values(6,2,4,90);
insert into test_new values(7,2,5,0);
insert into test_new values(8,3,4,0);
insert into test_new values(9,3,5,0);
insert into test_new values(10,4,5,40);
insert into test_new values(11,7,5,0);
insert into test_new values(12,9,4,0);
insert into test_new values(13,10,5,90);
insert into test_new values(14,11,5,70);
insert into test_new values(15,1,15,45);
```

in need this form The query show that

```
id  loc1 loc2  percentage
15    1    15       45
2    1    3       10
6    2    4       90
13   10   5       90
```

Not this one

```
id   loc1 loc2  percentage
2    1    3       10
15    1    15      45
6    2    4       90
13   10   5       90
```

Rules:

1. show `id, loc1, loc2, percentage` where percentage greater than zero.
2. remove any redundance of data in column `loc2` so the remove row that has lower value of percentage.
3. sort data  based on `percentage asc` and group it based column loc1.

Comment: Oracle database version 11g

Comment: You need to have that `oracle11g` in your tags - that's where such information belongs! So please: if you edit your post again, make sure to have that tag there so people will know what RDBMS you're using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
select t1.* from test_new t1
left join test_new t2
on t1.loc2 = t2.loc2 and t1.percentage < t2.percentage
where t1.percentage > 0 and t2.loc2 is null
order by t1.percentage
```

However, I think that based on your comments (not on your result table, which seems to be wrong), this is what you're expecting:

```
+----+------+------+------------+
| ID | LOC1 | LOC2 | PERCENTAGE |
+----+------+------+------------+
|  2 |    1 |    3 |         10 |
| 15 |    1 |   15 |         45 |
|  6 |    2 |    4 |         90 |
| 13 |   10 |    5 |         90 |
+----+------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Many thanks for you the results should be like this +----+------+------+------------+ | ID | LOC1 | LOC2 | PERCENTAGE | +----+------+------+------------+ | 15 | 1 | 15 | 45 | | 2 | 1 | 3 | 10 | | 6 | 2 | 4 | 90 | | 13 | 10 | 5 | 90 | +----+------+------+------------+

Comment: ordering inside grouping not ordering for all